# Overwatch doesn't give XP on competitive

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, counter-strike-go-overwatch

I recently finished some cases in Overwatch but I didn't get any XP for them. I then played a deathmatch on a Bloodhound Operation map and from this I got XP.

Do I have to play on a Bloodhound Operation map to receive XP from Overwatch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rationale for rewarding XP for Overwatch cases is laid out on the [**blog**](http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/overwatch/):

> You can earn XP by submitting accurate verdicts in your cases. After several of your cases have been resolved, you will receive an XP reward based on the overall accuracy of your recent verdicts, scaled by your Overwatch Investigator score.
>
> You can collect your reward by completing matches and earning XP in any official game mode.

So XP amount is based on the accuracy of your verdicts and your Investigator score, then it's awarded after matches in **any** "official game mode".

Comment: Just on a side note, how does is the further process done after the verdict is done? How do they decide if the verdict was accurate. And who handles those verdicts?

Answer (score 1):

As far as the community knows, it seems that exp for Overwatch cases come out after around 3-4 overwatch cases reviewed. Also note that it needs a verdict in order to get exp, meaning if you chose wrong you won't get any exp.

Comment: I completed 2 cases today and got XP in competitive. Thanks!